# Set axis limits in ggplot2 using pipes and fredr

Tags: r, ggplot2, pipe

I am trying to make a plot using St Louis Fed data, using the `fredr` package and the pipe (`%>%) command in` ggplot2`. I am struggling to use the` xlim()`or`lims()` command.

I can get the series I want to plot I with the following code.

```
#libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(fredr)
library(ggthemes)

#make the plot

map_dfr(c("LABSHPUSA156NRUG", "W273RE1A156NBEA"), fredr) %>%

pivot_wider(
   names_from = series_id, 
   values_from = value) %>%

mutate(., labour_share_of_profit = LABSHPUSA156NRUG/W273RE1A156NBEA)
```

So far so good. This gives me the data I need, with a new variable called `labour_share_of_profit`. The data (using `put()` is at the bottom of the question:

```
 > . + # A tibble: 93 × 6

   date       realtime_start realtime_end LABSHPUSA156NRUG W273RE1A156…¹ labou…²
   <date>     <date>         <date>                  <dbl>         <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 1950-01-01 2022-11-13     2022-11-13              0.628           5.7   0.110
 2 1951-01-01 2022-11-13     2022-11-13              0.634           5     0.127
 3 1952-01-01 2022-11-13     2022-11-13              0.645           5.1   0.126
 4 1953-01-01 2022-11-13     2022-11-13              0.644           4.8   0.134
 5 1954-01-01 2022-11-13     2022-11-13              0.637           5.2   0.123
 6 1955-01-01 2022-11-13     2022-11-13              0.627           6.1   0.103
 7 1956-01-01 2022-11-13     2022-11-13              0.640           5.6   0.114
 8 1957-01-01 2022-11-13     2022-11-13              0.639           5.3   0.121
 9 1958-01-01 2022-11-13     2022-11-13              0.636           4.8   0.132
10 1959-01-01 2022-11-13     2022-11-13              0.629           5.7   0.110
# … with 83 more rows, and abbreviated variable names ¹​W273RE1A156NBEA,
#   ²​labour_share_of_profit
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
>
```

So to pipe this to the plotting code I use:
%>%

```
ggplot(data = ., mapping = aes(x = date, y =labour_share_of_profit)) +
geom_line(lwd=1.2) +
labs(x = "Year", y = "Share of Labour Compensation as Proportion of Profit") +
theme(legend.position = "none") +
theme_wsj()

%>%

{ggsave(filename = "p1_wsj.pdf", 
     device = "pdf",
     width = 10*sqrt(2), height = 10)
 }
```

This produces the following plot.

[image]

Now, how do I use the `xlim()` function to set the plot limits for the beginning of the series? The two comments below don't do the job. I think it may be because of the way the date information is stored, and how it needs to be passed to `ggplot`.

The data using `put` for reproducibility is:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(-7305, -6940, -6575, -6209, 
-5844, -5479, -5114, -4748, -4383, -4018, -3653, -3287, -2922, 
-2557, -2192, -1826, -1461, -1096, -731, -365, 0, 365, 730, 1096, 
1461, 1826, 2191, 2557, 2922, 3287, 3652, 4018, 4383, 4748, 5113, 
5479, 5844, 6209, 6574, 6940, 7305, 7670, 8035, 8401, 8766, 9131, 
9496, 9862, 10227, 10592, 10957, 11323, 11688, 12053, 12418, 
12784, 13149, 13514, 13879, 14245, 14610, 14975, 15340, 15706, 
16071, 16436, 16801, 17167, 17532, 17897, -14975, -14610, -14245, 
-13880, -13514, -13149, -12784, -12419, -12053, -11688, -11323, 
-10958, -10592, -10227, -9862, -9497, -9131, -8766, -8401, -8036, 
-7670, 18262, 18628), class = "Date"), realtime_start = structure(c(19309, 
19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 
19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 
19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 
19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 
19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 
19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 
19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 
19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 
19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 
19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 
19309, 19309), class = "Date"), realtime_end = structure(c(19309, 
19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 
19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 
19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 
19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 
19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 
19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 
19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 
19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 
19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 
19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 19309, 
19309, 19309), class = "Date"), LABSHPUSA156NRUG = c(0.628362894058228, 
0.633731782436371, 0.644851565361023, 0.644496023654938, 0.637051999568939, 
0.626844048500061, 0.640427887439728, 0.638684749603271, 0.635847270488739, 
0.629354357719421, 0.636741697788239, 0.633703410625458, 0.629107296466827, 
0.626384675502777, 0.624378800392151, 0.619359791278839, 0.622894942760468, 
0.630079448223114, 0.634225606918335, 0.643875300884247, 0.64898556470871, 
0.63764888048172, 0.639445066452026, 0.640666723251343, 0.640968561172485, 
0.625560820102692, 0.62158989906311, 0.621596157550812, 0.622295022010803, 
0.62261962890625, 0.624348878860474, 0.614216029644012, 0.616743326187134, 
0.603852272033691, 0.601951777935028, 0.60230153799057, 0.607737004756927, 
0.615972578525543, 0.62066638469696, 0.611858665943146, 0.615197896957397, 
0.615098834037781, 0.620048463344574, 0.614196300506592, 0.607954382896423, 
0.607377409934998, 0.607116162776947, 0.609609842300415, 0.623013257980347, 
0.625988662242889, 0.637073159217834, 0.640336573123932, 0.629616677761078, 
0.621445715427399, 0.617115139961243, 0.605635344982147, 0.605510890483856, 
0.604003727436066, 0.604088604450226, 0.59113609790802, 0.587999582290649, 
0.592656254768372, 0.595092236995697, 0.593056976795197, 0.594270586967468, 
0.595646262168884, 0.593772530555725, 0.596151113510132, 0.594325959682465, 
0.597091138362885, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), W273RE1A156NBEA = c(5.7, 
5, 5.1, 4.8, 5.2, 6.1, 5.6, 5.3, 4.8, 5.7, 5.5, 5.4, 6.1, 6.4, 
6.8, 7.4, 7.3, 6.8, 6.3, 5.4, 4.5, 5, 5.4, 5.1, 4, 4.7, 5.3, 
5.7, 5.9, 5.2, 4, 4.7, 4.4, 5, 5.5, 5.5, 4.3, 4.3, 4.5, 4, 3.7, 
4.3, 4.2, 4.4, 5.2, 5.5, 5.9, 6.3, 5.3, 5, 3.9, 3.9, 5.4, 6, 
6.7, 6.7, 7, 5.6, 4.4, 5.8, 7.2, 7.2, 7.6, 7.4, 7.3, 6.9, 6.6, 
6.8, 7.2, 7.3, 8.9, 7, 3.2, -0.9, -1.2, 2.6, 3.9, 5.6, 5.7, 4.2, 
5.2, 6.7, 6, 5.4, 5.1, 5.2, 4.2, 3.7, 4.9, 6.5, 6.6, 7.2, 8.4
), labour_share_of_profit = c(0.110239104220742, 0.126746356487274, 
0.126441483404122, 0.134270004928112, 0.122509999917104, 0.10276131942624, 
0.114362122757094, 0.120506556528919, 0.132468181351821, 0.110413045213934, 
0.11577121777968, 0.117352483449159, 0.103132343683086, 0.0978726055473089, 
0.0918204118223751, 0.083697269091735, 0.085328074350749, 0.0926587423857521, 
0.100670731256879, 0.119236166830416, 0.144219014379713, 0.127529776096344, 
0.118415753046672, 0.125620926127714, 0.160242140293121, 0.13309804683036, 
0.117281113030776, 0.109051957465055, 0.105473732544204, 0.119734544020433, 
0.156087219715118, 0.130684261626386, 0.140168937769803, 0.120770454406738, 
0.109445777806369, 0.10950937054374, 0.141334187152774, 0.143249436866405, 
0.137925863265991, 0.152964666485786, 0.166269701880378, 0.143046240473903, 
0.147630586510613, 0.139590068296953, 0.116914304403158, 0.110432256351818, 
0.102901044538466, 0.0967634670318119, 0.117549671317047, 0.125197732448578, 
0.163352092107137, 0.164188864903572, 0.116595681066866, 0.103574285904566, 
0.0921067373076482, 0.0903933350719623, 0.086501555783408, 0.107857808470726, 
0.137292864647779, 0.101920016880693, 0.0816666086514791, 0.0823133687178294, 
0.0783016101310128, 0.0801428347020536, 0.081406929721571, 0.0863255452418673, 
0.0899655349326856, 0.0876692813985488, 0.0825452721781201, 0.0817933066250527, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -93L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please make a reproducible example next time with `df <- dput()`.

Comment: Done. Apologies for not doing this at the outset. I hadn't thought it necessary since `fredr()` downloads the data.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `coord_cartesian`. Here you can set the range of the x- and y-axis. For example `xlim = c(1950,2020)`.

```
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(date = year(date)) %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = date, y =labour_share_of_profit)) +
    geom_line(lwd=1.2) +
    labs(x = "Year", y = "Share of Labour Compensation as Proportion of Profit") +
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    theme_wsj() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1950,2020))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below will allow you to set custom label ranges (although it doesn't limit/filter the data):

```
ggplot(data = ., mapping = aes(x = date, y =labour_share_of_profit)) +
geom_line(lwd=1.2) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks=1950:2020) +
labs(x = "Year", y = "Share of Labour Compensation as Proportion of Profit") +
theme(legend.position = "none") +
theme_wsj()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option would be to get rid of the `NA` values in your data which are the reason why your `x` scale starts at 1929:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

ggplot(subset(dat, !is.na(labour_share_of_profit)), aes(x = date, y = labour_share_of_profit)) +
  geom_line(lwd = 1.2) +
  labs(x = "Year", y = "Share of Labour Compensation as Proportion of Profit") +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme_wsj()
```

[image]